# Como comparar as diferenças entre 2 dll's

Tags: dll

Tenho 2 dll's  e preciso comparar quais diferenças entre elas, `autauth.dll` e `auth1.dll`.

Tentei comparar com **PE explorer**, mas sem sucesso, alguma ideia de como faço isso?

Comment: Você quer saber se eles são idênticos?

Comment: Seja bem vindo, by the way - aproveite e faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber melhor como o site funciona e veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) que tipo de perguntas são aceitas. Ah, e o site é só em português - por favor [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/209269/edit) sua pergunta e remova a versão em inglês... :)

Comment: Tira um hash das duas, se o hash for o mesmo, elas são idênticas.

Answer (score 0):

Faça um Hash dos dois arquivos para saber se são idênticos. Para saber se todas as funções exportadas das duas DLLs são iguais ou para fazer comparações das funções, use o aplicativo "DLL export Viewer" [link](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda T.Bandeira a lance do hash eu ja sabia, mas precisava mesmo era saber quais as diferenças nas funções! Vou instalar e testar o software que vc sugeriu :D